# Appium inspector screen isn’t running in parallel while script in eclipse is executed

Tags: android, selenium-webdriver, appium, ui-automation, inspector

I'm using appium inspector with android app on Mac OS, 
while i run my scripts of test cases and see inspector, the screen isn't changing in real time. Only the login screen is displayed! But on my android device, the screen is loading normally from screen to screen for each test case.

Comment: I don't think inspector screen changes by itself. You have to capture the screen shot manually.

Comment: So always i have to tap refresh button ? It is a native behaviour ? there is no possible way to change it by adding a framework or some thing like that?

Comment: I am not aware of any framework but yes you have to refresh it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah @Gaurav is right. It is not possible to auto-refresh it in appium. If you run on windows [droid @ screen](http://droid-at-screen.org/download.html) is a nice tool.

Comment: this tool isn't available in MAC OS?
I'm using inspector for both Android and IOS application with MAC.

Comment: Try [vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm/related) . Vysor is an chrome browser addon. Vysor lets you view and control your Android on your computer. Easy peasy. Its response time is very good.